# Read a PDF file on Google Chrome on 2 columns

Tags: pdf, chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can display a PDF file on two columns on Google Chrome (I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate).

I.e. instead of having:

[image]

I would like to see something like:

[image]

3 columns would be even nicer in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Why must it be an extension?  I use Firefox, not Chrome, but have it set to open PDFs in an external application.  There are scads of Windows PDF viewer apps, and displaying PDFs in two pages on a landscape display is a common setting.  What I use here is the open source SumatraPDF application (https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) It gets the nod because it also displays ePub, Mobi, XPS, DjVu, CHM, and Comic Book (CBZ and CBR) files.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Kami](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kami-pdf-and-document-mar/ecnphlgnajanjnkcmbpancdjoidceilk?hl=en)? Although it does more than simply enabling you to display a PDF file on two columns on Google Chrome (like, annotate, highlight, comment, draw on PDFs, etc.) it still does what you'd like it to (although no 3 columns, I am afraid). If you are ok with these supplementary functionalities, maybe it is worth a look.

I am using it for myself and I must say I am happy with how it works.